# Accessing multiple variables from 'separated' classes (no visibility)

Tags: java, class, proxy, setter, getter

Let's says I have 3 classes, A, B & C

Class A, 'knows about' both class B and class C.

However, class B doesn't know about class C and I have a need to access quite a few variables from objects that are located in Class C from class B.

I can put a simple 'Getter' or 'Proxy' method into class A which allows me to access the required object's variables, however, as there are many of them (20+) it seems like a pretty long winded way of doing this.

I can't move the variables into the other class as it breaks other parts of my code (my actual code is about 24 classes so I don't want to be doing major surgery on it!)

What would be an accepteable method to access these variables?

Help appreciated

[image]

Comment: What about a `getB()` accessor in class `A`?

Comment: If you have a lot of "data objects", and if manually creating getters and setters seems daunting, have a look at [Project Lombok](http://projectlombok.org/). Using annotations, you can mark fields and have getters and setters created automatically at compile-time without needing to write or see any of the code in your files or editor.

Comment: Not to distract too much from the OP's question, but I'm curious about Lombok, which I never heard of before. Just watched the demo video. How about customizing setters to, for instance, null is not allowed, or a number has to be in a certain range, or whatever? I also wonder about how good its JavaDoc turns out to be, when the functions don't exist in your source. Interesting concept.

Comment: Thanks @aliteralmind, can I ask something?  If I do as you suggest, I can access Class C's objects from B like so:  getA().object.variable.......is this any better than just saying a.object.variable (which I understand isn't good practice as it's apparently breaks the rule of Demeter)?  Thanks!

Comment: @aliteralmind I've only used Lombok for simple getters and setters myself, and I absolutely love it for that. It has a "NotNull" annotation for method parameters, and it looks like there is an [experimental feature](http://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/onX.html) that allows you to use it with the other annotations as well.

Comment: How do you make a link like that in a comment!? I keep seeing it and don't know how!  :)  <A HREF="http://usatoday.com">usatoday</A>  DAMMIT!

Comment: @aliteralmind There's a yellow box right below the textarea you type in that explains how comments use "mini-Markdown formatting". Link text in square brackets, followed by the URL in parentheses. If you don't see it, click "help" below the "Add Comment" button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless there is a disadvantage to providing wholesale access, there could be a simple accessor to the entire B object, which would preclude having to maintain anything in `A`, such as when getters or setters are added or deleted from `B`.

It's not necessarily a bad thing to have an access function for each variable in B, however, as this is the basic concept behind composition ([as opposed to](https://www.google.com/search?q=composition%20not%20inheritance%20java) inheritance). It's a pain to maintain this boilerplate, but it's not always unreasonable to do so.

As to your just-posted question: This would result in `C` accessing everything in `B` via two dots, as you say: `aInstance.getB().getSomethingInB()`. But you're either going to maintain the boilerplate in `A`, or you're going to maintain the double-dot-accessors when using them in `C`. I'd choose double-dots, at least in this case.

I gotta look up the Demeter thing  :)

Comment: Thanks @aliteralmind, what I've done is, if my object is in class C, I've put the accessor in class B, the accessor returns c.myObject (thereby using only one dot, where c is an instance of C) then from B I can simply say getCObject().variable - again, one dot, just means I have to write an accessor for each object, but this is perfectly doable, at least I don't need to write one for each variable!  Thanks for this! :-)

Comment: Excellent. Glad it helped. And thank you for the big green checkmark! :)